# Twitter4j IDs to Array

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am attempting to compare two lists. One list contains everyone I am following on twitter, the other is everyone who follows me. I don't know how to do this since .getFollowersIDs and .getFriendsIDs are of type ID. I have looked this up, but I can't understand how to compare the results of this type. I tried treating it like they both were arrays, but Eclipse didn't like that.. 
http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/IDs.html

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to IDs

```
package com.follow3d.rob;

import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;

public class Follow3d {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxx")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxx")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxx")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxx");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        try {
                long ID = twitter.getId();//Personal Twitter ID.
                IDs FOLLOWERS = twitter.getFollowersIDs(-1);//Numeric Array of every user that follows me. 
                IDs FOLLOWING = twitter.getFriendsIDs(-1);//Numeric Array of every user I am following. 
                while (FOLLOWING.hasNext() == true)
                {
                    int counter = 0;
                    if (FOLLOWING[counter] != FOLLOWERS[counter])//ERROR HERE.
                }
            } catch (TwitterException name) {
                System.out.println("You don't have internet connection.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about [this](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/IDs.html#getIDs--)? Google first, please.

Comment: Yes, I tried. That is why I posted the link above, and constructed this question with an attempt trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/IDs.html), FOLLOWERS and FOLLOWING are of type `IDs` (not array) and hence, we can't reference any element inside it by `index`.

If we need to compare the followers and following user ids then, we need to use `getIDs()` method of `IDs` class (i.e. FOLLOWERS and FOLLOWING `objects`) and iterate through them. Also, instead of iterating using `while` loop (as shown in the example), we need to iterate FOLLOWING array for each element of FOLLOWERS array to see if an id exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

[`IDs::getIDs()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/IDs.html#getIDs--) gives you a `long[]`. I think this is what you want.